# Migrate executing the Baseline again?

Tags: flyway, migrate, baseline

I have baselined my existing database with a V1__Base_version.sql. Now, when I run migrate and have files like V2__Migration_842.sql and V3__Migration_842.sql, my V1__Base_version.sql gets executed again and fails with the following message :

PS: I rename the .sql files during my build appending a timeStamp to it so no 2 developers get the same file name after checking-in.

> Migration 20170401092116374__V1__Base_version.sql failed
>   -------------------------------------------------------- SQL State  : 42P07 Error Code : 0 Message    : ERROR: relation "address_space"
>   already exists Location   :
>   /Users/code/main/migration/resources/sql/20170401092116374__V1__Base_version.sql
>   (/Users/code/main/migration/resources/sql/20170401092116374__V1__Base_version.sql)
>   Line       : 33 Statement  : CREATE TABLE address_space (   id
>   character varying(32) NOT NULL,   address_type character varying(255)
>   NOT NULL,   last_modified_timestamp timestamp without time zone )  }]

My baseline succeeds with the following message :

> - Creating Metadata table: "public"."schema_version"
> - Successfully baselined schema with version: 1
> - Current version of schema "public": 1
> - Migrating schema "public" to version 20170401092116374 - V1  Base version

Should not the migrate ignore the 20170401092116374__V1__Base_version.sql? I have set the BaselineOnMigrate and ValidateOnMigrate flags to false.

The 3 .sql file names after the build are as follows :

1. 20170401092116374__V1__Base_version.sql
2. 20170512102926635__V2__Migration_for_8_4_3.sql
3. 20170531164538687__V3__Migration_843.sql

What is that I am missing here???

Thanks

Comment: Can someone help???

Comment: I started having the same issue today after changing the contents of the `V1__Base_version.sql` file.

A developer ran a migration manually between baselining and running any migrations in production, so I updated the baseline file with the latest schema dump. This same issue is occurring. I started using flyway on an existing schema, so did not create the schema from the baseline. I have the same flags as OP set to false.